# многомерный массив, if и переменная

Tags: php

Есть форма где юзер выбирает какой список показать (почта, емайл, все). В запросе уже написано условие (`WHERE from = '1'` или `WHERE from = '0'` или без условия) Есть многомерный массив, в нем есть ключ `[from]`, значения которого могут быть `0` или `1`.  по которому создается массив. Вывожу

```
if ($data[0]['from'] == '1') {
    echo "текст";
} else {
    echo "другой текст";
}
```

А как вывести все вместе, когда в ключе `[from]` есть и `0` и `1`?

Вот часть массива

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [from] => 0
        [data_num] => 8
        [input_date] => 2017-07-04
        [description] => fgfgfg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [from] => 1
        [data_num] => 7
        [input_date] => 2017-07-03
        [description] => asd
    )
)
```

Comment: Вы не видите противоречия? Как там может быть одновременно и 0 и 1?

Comment: нужно написать еще одно условие elseif а  как не знаю.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 1):

если я правильно понял, то просто есть массив в котором под ключом "from" лежит значение 0 или 1, в зависимости от значения нужно что то вывести, но может быть ситуация что там лежит "01" или "10". если так то:

```
if ($data[0]['from'] === '1') {
   echo "текст";
}elseif ($data[0]['from'] === '0') {
   echo "другой текст";
}else {
   echo "третий текст";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вот так:

```
if ($data[0]['from'] == 0 && $data[1]['from'] == 1) {
        echo "текст";
    } else {
        echo "другой текст";
    }
```

Comment: я бы мог это использовать если бы проверял разные ключи

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял вы хотите проверку вот такого типа:

```
if (in_array($data[0]['from'], [1, 2])) {
    echo "текст";
} else {
    echo "другой текст";
}
```

или

```
if ($data[0]['from'] == 1 || $data[0]['from'] == 2) {
    echo "текст";
} else {
    echo "другой текст";
}
```

или

```
switch ($data[0]['from']) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        echo "текст";
    break;

    default:
        echo "другой текст";
    break;
}
```

Везде результат будет одинаковый, реализацию выберите любую какая вам больше нравиться.

Comment: это же многомерный массив $data[0]['from'] может быть = 0, а $data[1]['from'] = 1. Мне надо как бы их объединить

Comment: Полный код тогда покажите, что в $data и как с ним работаете

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Добавил часть массива.